# How to add custom header to AFNetworking on a JSONRequestOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking, nsurlrequest

Hi, I have the following code accessing a URL:

```
NSString * stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/someAPI", kSERVICE_URL, kSERVICE_VERSION];
NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]];

AFJSONRequestOperation * operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    completionHandler(JSON, nil);
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    completionHandler(nil, error);
}];
```

But I want to pass the user token as a parameter on `HEADER`, like `X-USER-TOKEN`.

Cant find it on `AFNetworking documentation`, should I change the operation type?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `AFHTTPClient` or subclass it!

You can set default headers with `-setDefaultHeader:value:` like this :

```
[self setDefaultHeader:@"X-USER-TOKEN" value:userToken];
```

You can check the [documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.3/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/setDefaultHeader:value:)

Comment: For AFN version 2.x and AFHTTPRequestOperationManager, you could do it like this:
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

Answer (score 28):

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

[request setValue: @"X-USER-TOKEN"  forHTTPHeaderField:@"< clientToken >"];

[AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest: request ...]
```

Comment: I think its the opposite right? X-USER-TOKEN on HTTPHeaderField

Comment: maybe ;). I don't know if X-USER-TOKEN was the variable value or the field name

Comment: Now its addValue, and not setValue :)

Answer (score 8):

I did this :)

```
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Token token=\"%@\"", _userObj.oAuth] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Comment: Getting an error No Known instance method for selector 'setValue:forHTTPHeaderField'

Answer (score 3):

If you have a layer of abstraction, let's say APIManager,
then you should do the following inside a particular method

```
 [[HTTPClient sharedHTTPClient].requestSerializer setValue:YOUR_KEY forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Register"];
```