# After setting custom headers in AFNetworking 2.x, the parameters are not being received by the RESTful API

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I followed the suggested solution at [AFNetworking 2.0 add headers to GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466291/afnetworking-2-0-add-headers-to-get-request) to specify custom headers for the request with the following code snippet:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:someID forHTTPHeaderField:@"some_id"];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"id": user.id, @"birthday": user.birthday};
[manager POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/user_create",BaseURLString] parameters:parameters
 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     if (responseObject[@"error"])
     {
         NSLog(@"REST User Create Response Error: %@", responseObject[@"error"]);
     }
     else
     {
         [self saveUserDetails:responseObject];
     }
 }
 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"REST User Create Error: %@", error);

 }];
```

But what happens when this gets executed is I get an error in the response from the API stating all my parameters are missing.  This same block of code used to work before (without setting the custom header and when the API didn't require them originally).

Does anybody know how to properly set both custom headers and POST parameters?

Thanks,
Nino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I should have set my request serializer to the following instead since my API doesn't require JSON-formatted parameters.

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
```

Hope this helps others dealing with the same situation as mine.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine to me.

A few things to try:

1. Try using [AFNetworkActivityLogger](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger) to see what's actually being sent (set it to `AFLoggerLevelDebug`.)  You can also use a web proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or a protocol analyzer like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).
2. If you determine the data is not being sent properly, set a breakpoint in `[AFURLRequestSerialization -requestBySerializingRequest:withParameters:error:]`.  This is where your HTTP headers and parameters are added to the URL request.  The method is pretty straightforward; you should be able to step through and watch as stuff is added to the request and determine why it gets skipped.

   **NOTE:** AFURLRequestSerialization.m contains multiple subclasses of AFURLRequestSerialization.  Set a breakpoint in the super implementation, as well as in the AFJSONRequestSerializer implementation.

   Examples that could cause this behavior:

   - `parameters` is `nil`.
   - you've added `POST` to `HTTPMethodsEncodingParametersInURI` but

     - your API is not prepared to handle parameters appended to a URL on a POST request, or
     - the `queryStringSerialization` block is `nil` AND `queryStringSerializationStyle` is set to something other than `AFHTTPRequestQueryStringDefaultStyle`.
   - NSJSONSerialization can't handle your `parameters` dictionary

One side note (unrelated to your problem), if you use AFHTTPRequestOperationManager's `initWithBaseURL:` method, and keep a strong reference to your manager, you won't have to do that `[NSString -stringWithFormat:`] stuff  to construct your URL.