# AFNetworking Stripe API

Tags: curl, afnetworking, stripe-payments

I'm trying to convert the following cURL request to AFNetworking but am unsure how to go about doing it.

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens \
   -u XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: \
   -d bank_account[country]=CA \
   -d bank_account[currency]=cad \
   -d bank_account[name]="Jane Austen" \
   -d bank_account[account_holder_type]=individual \
   -d bank_account[routing_number]=110000000 \
   -d bank_account[account_number]=000123456789
```

Here's my AFNetworking code.

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *params = @{@"bank_account[country]": @"CA",
                         @"ubank_account[currency]": @"cad",
                         @"bank_account[name]":@"Jane Austen",
                         @"bank_account[account_holder_type]": @"individual",
                         @"bank_account[routing_number]":@"110000000",
                         @"bank_account[account_number]": @"000123456789"
                         };
[manager POST:@"https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

I'm unsure what to do with the -u flag.

Answer (score 1):

The curl `-u` flag simply means that [basic auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) should be used. The API key is the username, and the password is empty.

I'm not familiar with AFNetworking but I think [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12440149/5307473) should have the information you need to implement basic auth.

Alternatively, instead of using basic auth, you can also add a special header to your request:

```
Authorization: Bearer sk_...
```

This [other StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19467000/5307473) explains how to add additional headers to a request.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to include the Authorization: Bearer?

Comment: Just use one or the other. The `Bearer` header is the recommended way, but both work equally fine in practice.