# AFNetworking send header with request

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have been searching for hours and found answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20343652/3086197) :
but when i send the Authorization like this :

```
    AFHTTPSessionManager* manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
        manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
        //header = [header stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];

        //[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"text/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        //[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"text/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [manager.requestSerializer setValue:header forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
        /*
        NSLog(@"headers: %@",manager.requestSerializer.HTTPRequestHeaders);
        this printed : {
            "Accept-Language" = "en;q=1";
            Authorization =  "Bearer eyJ0eXAiO";
            "User-Agent" = "Virtuocity/1.0 (iPhone; iOS 10.2; Scale/2.00)";
        }
        */
        [manager GET:url parameters:dic progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {
        } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
            block(responseObject,nil);
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
            block(nil,error);
        }];
```

but the server gave me the following error:

```
serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)  headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "accept, accept-language, content-type, accept, authorization, moduleid, tabid, x-dnn-moniker";
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "GET, POST, PUT, HEAD, OPTIONS";
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    "Content-Length" = 61;
    "Content-Type" = "text/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Sun, 29 Jan 2017 10:18:36 GMT";
    Expires = "-1";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    "Set-Cookie" = "dnn_IsMobile=False; path=/; HttpOnly, dnn_IsMobile=False; path=/; HttpOnly, language=en-US; path=/; HttpOnly";
}
```

i observed that the returned headers from the error don't include the 'Authorization' header i sent them , and i doubt that is because of the white space sent in the header so i don't know what is wrong and i tried the same request on **POST MAN** and worked perfectly so what to do now ?

Comment: What is the value of `header`? Can you provide a screenshot of the post man configuration of the endpoint?

Comment: this is the bulk edit mode of my header in postman
Authorization:Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzaWQiOiIwOGQ0NDgzOTcxYjYxYzA3OGEzZmMzNzNlNDc0MDhlZiIsInJvbGUiOlsiUmVnaXN0ZXJlZCBVc2VycyIsIlN1YnNjcmliZXJzIiwiRUxFQUdVRSBNYWpvciAyMDE3IC0gQXRsYW50YSIsIkdhbWVycyBBc3NlbWJseSAyMDE3IEhTIiwiUGlyYXRlcyIsIkVhc3QgVmFsbGV5IEtuaWdodHMiLCJSRUQiXSwiaXNzIjoiMTcyLjE2LjAuMjE2IiwiZXhwIjoxNDg1NjkyNjkyLCJuYmYiOjE0ODU2ODg3OTJ9.9naWvfqzZHC1XnqnNgDoQxJWhyGg64HkNb1fwETQAR4

Comment: There should not be "Authorization:" in the string, it should just be "Bearer [...]"

Comment: [manager.requestSerializer setValue:header forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"]; 
and my header string = @"Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzaWQiOiIwOGQ0NDgzOTc‌​xYjYxYzA3OGEzZmMzNzN‌​lNDc0MDhlZiIsInJvbGU‌​iOlsiUmVnaXN0ZXJlZCB‌​Vc2VycyIsIlN1YnNjcml‌​iZXJzIiwiRUxFQUdVRSB‌​NYWpvciAyMDE3IC0gQXR‌​sYW50YSIsIkdhbWVycyB‌​Bc3NlbWJseSAyMDE3IEh‌​TIiwiUGlyYXRlcyIsIkV‌​hc3QgVmFsbGV5IEtuaWd‌​odHMiLCJSRUQiXSwiaXN‌​zIjoiMTcyLjE2LjAuMjE‌​2IiwiZXhwIjoxNDg1Njk‌​yNjkyLCJuYmYiOjE0ODU‌​2ODg3OTJ9.9naWvfqzZH‌​C1XnqnNgDoQxJWhyGg64‌​HkNb1fwETQAR4 "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found out that AFNetworking is sending some sort of cookies by default and the api i am dealing with won't check for Authorization if there are cookies to check so i disabled sending cookies with this line and it worked ^__^

```
[manager.requestSerializer setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
```