# Proxy error in iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, ios-frameworks

Hi I am working on a frame work. I am using NSURLProtocol to interceptor the request. In the request I am adding proxy with Username and password.

its perfectly working in the curl
- curl proxy with username and paswword..

when I am changing the header in the request, In the response I am getting this error.

Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"

code which I am using

```
-(void)startLoading {
        NSMutableURLRequest *newRequest = [self.request mutableCopy];
     NSURLSessionConfiguration* config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration;
           // config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{ @"Accept":@"application/json"};
            NSDictionary *proxyDict = [self getProxyDictionary];
            if (proxyDict.allKeys.count >= 1){
                config.connectionProxyDictionary = proxyDict;

     NSString *authorizationToken = ["username" stringByAppendingString:@":"] stringByAppendingString: "password"];
config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{@"Accept": @"application/json",@"Proxy-Authorization":authorizationToken};
            }
    }
```

If I run in the webview, I am getting this error

```
TypeError: must start with number, buffer, array or string
 
 at fromObject (buffer.js:138:11)
   at new Buffer (buffer.js:65:10)
   at module.exports (/apps/infinity/freeg-proxy/trans-proxy/app/http/authenticator.js:12:19)
   at call (/apps/infinity/freeg-proxy/trans-proxy/node_modules/connect/index.js:239:7)
   at next (/apps/infinity/freeg-proxy/trans-proxy/node_modules/connect/index.js:183:5)
   at Function.handle (/apps/infinity/freeg-proxy/trans-proxy/node_modules/connect/index.js:186:3)
   at Server.app (/apps/infinity/freeg-proxy/trans-proxy/node_modules/connect/index.js:51:37)
   at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)`enter code here`
   at Server.emit (events.js:172:7)
   at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:528:12)
   at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:103:23)
```

Can any one help for me.

Comment: Could you share your code? Where you are setting the header and proxy

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: Maybe could be because you are receiving a content-type `"text/html"`and you are setting it to `"application/json`"?

Comment: I am using AFNetworking. If I change to text/html its working. I have given both then also its not working.

Comment: I think it must be because how you are setting the headers. Take a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19467000/6203030 and try to set headers in that way

Comment: as I see that link I am adding header in start loading is that need to done in NSURLSessionDataTask. It is because of that.